# Excel Interop Secondary AxisGroup only appearing sometimes

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

So, I wrote a short little C# program that will take some text files and produce some scatterplots out of them. The plot has 2 series on it and 2 y-axes. For some reason, the second series does not appear on every run. However, it always appears if you step through the program with the debugger.

My code for the 2 series is as follows:

```
        //show records data

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series series1b = seriesCollection2.NewSeries();
        series1b.AxisGroup = XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary;
        series1b.Name = "Records";
        series1b.XValues = ws.get_Range("A" + FACT_TABLE_START.ToString() + ":A" + FACT_TABLE_END.ToString());
        series1b.Values = ws.get_Range("D" + FACT_TABLE_START.ToString() + ":D" + FACT_TABLE_END.ToString());

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        //show duration data
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series series2b = seriesCollection2.NewSeries();
        series2b.AxisGroup = XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary;
        series2b.Name = "Duration";
        series2b.XValues = ws.get_Range("A" + FACT_TABLE_START.ToString() + ":A" + FACT_TABLE_END.ToString());
        series2b.Values = ws.get_Range("E" + FACT_TABLE_START.ToString() + ":E" + FACT_TABLE_END.ToString());
```

Probably about 3/4 of the time, the second series will appear just fine. But the other 1/4, series2b will not appear on the plot. I am guessing something asynchronous is going on here? I added the Sleep(500) statement because it seemed to  make series2b appear more often.

Why are my graphs only sometimes being created properly?

Comment: What happens if you use the Refresh method of the Chart object?

Comment: Refresh() doesn't doing anything. I have found actually that only every second run, the secondary axis will appear. So it actually only works exactly half of the time. @MacroMarc

Comment: Okay, no idea why this worked, but I added a Thread.Sleep(500) after the last line, and now it seems to work 100% of the time. Although I am not sure why.